# Getting a query set between a range of dates Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

I'm trying to return a list of items in between 2 different dates, a date in the past and the current time using a queryset.

The error I'm getting is **TypeError: an integer is required (got type str)**

**views.py**

```
import datetime
import pytz

first_date = "2020-01-01 19:17:35.909424"
last_date = timezone.now()
```

I don't want anything returned that has a date in the future

Here is the filter in the query

```
.filter(hide_sentance_until=(date(first_date), date(last_date)))
```

This is the full queryset, but it's the above filter causing he issue

```
zip_flash_sentances = (
    model.objects
    .filter(show_sentance=True)
    .filter(
        hide_sentance_until=(date(first_date), date(last_date))
    )
    .order_by("?")
    .filter(username_id = user_id_fk)
    .values_list('sentance_eng', 'sentance_esp', 'id')
    .first()
 )
```

I thought it might be a comparison problem with dates but here is my model field

**models.py**

```
hide_sentance_until = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now(), blank=True)
```

Thanks

Comment: Where is the `date` function coming from?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `gte` and `lte` query attributes:

```
first_datetime = datetime.datetime.strptime(first_date, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')
last_date = timezone.now()


.filter(hide_sentance_until__lte=last_date,hide_sentance_until__gte=first_time)
```

Answer (score 0):

One thing is that you're specifying a specific value that's determined when your code is compiled to be your default value. To have the actual current date be the value you want:

```
hide_sentance_until = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now, blank=True)
```

Then you need to parse the datetime out of the string.

```
date_value = datetime.strptime(first_date, DATETIME_FORMAT_YOU_USE)
```

Where DATETIME_FORMAT_YOU_USE is the [series of format codes from Python](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-format-codes) that you're using.

Finally you should use the `__range` queryset field lookup.

```
.filter(
    hide_sentance_until__range=(date_value, timezone.now())
)
```